# Issues with css flex and input boxes

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, styled-components

I have 2 lists side by side. These line up nicely, but when I add the input boxes it goes out of sync. Any idea why this is happening? My code is below. And also screenshots.

Please find [codesandbox here too](https://codesandbox.io/s/1r694y3y1q).

```
const Wrapper = styled.article`
    width: 240px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0 8px 0;
`;

const Header = styled.p`
    font-size: 15px;
`;

const Options = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const Option = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
`;

const FirstOption = styled(Option)`
    justify-content: flex-end;
`;

const Text = styled.p`
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 4px 0;
`;

const Left = styled.div`
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 5px;
`;

const Right = styled.div`
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
`;


<Wrapper>
     <Header>Choose your teams</Header>
     <Options>
        <Left>
            <input type="text" />
            {teams.map(currency => (
                <FirstOption>
                   <Text>{team}</Text>
                </FirstOption>
             ))}
        </Left>

        <Right>
            <input type="text" />
            {teams.map(team => (
                <Option>
                    <Text>{team}</Text>
                </Option>
            ))}
        </Right>
     </Options>
</Wrapper>
```

This is what its looks like

[image]

This is what it should look like, but with the input boxes.

[image]

Comment: I ran into a similar problem a while back, which was caused by the default `size` attribute (defaults to 20). I ended up doing this: `<input size='1'/>`. This kept the default size from interfering with the flex. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#size) for more info.

Comment: try `width:100%` on input

Comment: @David784 this didn't work. I saw some other answer saying this and tried that, but no luck. The trick was 100% width and border-box

Comment: @TemaniAfif I had added `width: 100%`, but also needed box-sizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by add

```
const Input = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`;
```

and change

```
<input type="text" /> to <Input type="text" />
```

I fix this here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/xv93wl893z

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.article`
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0 8px 0;
`;

const Header = styled.p`
  font-size: 15px;
`;

const Options = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const Option = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
`;

const FirstOption = styled(Option)`
  justify-content: flex-end;
`;

const Text = styled.p`
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 4px 0;
`;

const Left = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 5px;
`;

const Right = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`;

const teams = ["Liverpool", "Chelsea", "Fulham"];

function App() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header>Choose your team</Header>
      <Options>
        <Left>
          <Input type="text" />
          {teams.map(team => (
            <FirstOption key={team}>
              <Text>{team}</Text>
            </FirstOption>
          ))}
        </Left>

        <Right>
          <Input type="text" />
          {teams.map(team => (
            <Option>
              <Text>{team}</Text>
            </Option>
          ))}
        </Right>
      </Options>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: nice man, so `border-box` was the fix. Are you able to explain why that was needed?

Comment: The box-sizing property defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `width: 100%;` and `box-sizing: border-box` to `<input>`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.article`
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0 8px 0;
`;

const Header = styled.p`
  font-size: 15px;
`;

const Options = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const Option = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
`;

const FirstOption = styled(Option)`
  justify-content: flex-end;
`;

const Text = styled.p`
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 4px 0;
`;

const Left = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 5px;
`;

const Right = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
`;

const teams = ["Liverpool", "Chelsea", "Fulham"];

function App() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header>Choose your team</Header>      
        <Options>                 
          <Left>
          <input style={{ width: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box'}} type="text" />
            {teams.map(team => (
              <FirstOption key={team}>
                <Text>{team}</Text>
              </FirstOption>
            ))}
          </Left>

          <Right>
            <input style={{ width: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box' }} type="text" />
            {teams.map(team => (
              <Option>
                <Text>{team}</Text>
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Right>
        </Options>    
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: nice man, so `border-box` was the fix. Are you able to explain why that was needed?